# Changing style of top bar

Tags: 2013, ribbon

I'm trying to brand the ribbon/title bar of a site but cannot find options outside of the default themes provided. Was this removed in 2013?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in 2013 you have to edit the master page directly to style it beyond the built-in themes. better yet, you can "legally" design master pages from scratch (now a supported feature) and set the CSS howver you like. microsoft calls it the "design manager" option of publishing sites. check it out here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj822363.aspx

the style that controls the top bar specifically is #suiteBarLeft

this guy has a good tutorial on it: http://blogs.askcts.com/2013/03/05/sharepoint-2013-branding-the-top-bar-the-importance-of-browser-testing/

hope that helps!